# Strange code on Java Static Initialization Blocks

Tags: java, static, initializer, jls

When going through the JLS [8.3.2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2) I wasn't able to understand the following code.

```
class Z {
static { i = j + 2; }
static int i, j;
static { j = 4; }
}
```

The code is resulting in the error `Cannot reference a field before it is defined`

But if I change the code to

```
class Z {
static { i = 2; }
static int i, j;
static { j = 4; }
}
```

The code is getting compiled. But in both the cases the variable definition is after the initialization block. What is the mystery behind this?

Comment: They are declarations, known before any code is ran... this is like asking why can I call a method from a method that's defined above the method to be called

Comment: @Esailija: Whats the difference between `i` and `j`. Why error for `j` only? It will be good if you provide more information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can *assign* to a value earlier than its declaration - you just can't *read* it. So this fails too:

```
static { System.out.println(j + 2); }
static int j;
```

Whereas this is fine:

```
static { j = 5; }
static int j;
```

One of the four conditions in [section 8.3.2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2.3) for an invalid usage is:

- The usage is not on the left hand side of an assignment.

(The double-negatives in that section are making my head hurt, but I *think* it relevant!)

To be honest, that part of the spec is one of the worst I've seen - it's *really* unclear. But the upshot is that you can assign but not read :)

Comment: Did you mean - `you just *can't* read it`, in your first statement.

Answer (score 1):

Actually,Its an compiler basics,

the assignment statements are executed from **right to left.**

e.g.`i=2;`

it means 2 is assigned to i,and 2 is constant hence no need to declare it

In the other hand if we write

```
i=j+2;
```

it will compile j first and then assign it to the i hence it causes the error because j is not defined yet.

Answer (score 0):

In `i = j + 2;` you use the variable `j`  that is initialize in a different static block.

You should put everything togheter, in only one static block, the `j` initialization and the expression to get  the code compiled. This code works:

```
public class Z {

    static int i, j;
    static { j = 4; 
            i = j + 2; }

}
```

Davide